# How to total the amount form database

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to know
I Have a field in mysql database sells and when I want the result it shows me total amount of sells in php

For example

```
Id   items  sells
1    item1  1000
2    item2   1500
3    item3   500

  Total    3000
```

Answer (score 1):

use MySQL [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) :-

```
select SUM(sells) as Total from table
```

> The `SUM()` function returns the total sum of a numeric column.

Comment: What if we do it in php... while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){ $t += $row['sells']; } echo $t;

Comment: select SUM(sells) as sells from table

Comment: Try this query with your code